# Set a maximum iteration for Bisection Method?

Tags: r, maximize

How can I set a maximum iteration = 20 for the following Bisection Method code? Should I work on feval only or something else?

```
rf.bisection <- function(f, lower, upper, tol=1e-4) { 
flow <- f(lower) 
fupper <- f(upper) 
feval <- 2 

if (flow * fupper > 0) stop("The given interval does not contain the root!
\n") 
diff <- upper - lower 

while (abs(diff) > tol) { 
    newpoint <- (lower + upper) / 2 
    newf <- f(newpoint) 
    if (abs(newf) <= tol) break 
    if (flow * newf < 0) upper <- newpoint 
    if (fupper * newf < 0) lower <- newpoint 
    diff <- upper - lower 
    feval <- feval + 1 
} 
list(x = newx, value = newf, fevals=feval) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition in `while` to `while (abs(diff) > tol & feval<22)`. 22 because in first iteration `feval` is already 2.

Comment: That will only give you 18 iterations, unless you initialize `feval` with 0.

Comment: @eugen, you are right, I was thinking about function evaluations, fixed.

Comment: @GuessGucci if you think this answer is good enough, please mark it as accepted so the question wont show in unanswered questions list.

Comment: I did, but the system told me to wait for like 7 minutes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the time limit.